# Time based sliding window in R

Tags: r

I want to calculate a time-based sliding window in R.
My data frame has the columnames: `id`, `rec_time`, `pupil_x`, `pupil_y`.
I want to calculate descriptive statistics for each window. The window size should be 30 seconds, the step size 15 seconds.

I am aware of the function `rollapply` of the package `zoo`.
But I don´t know how to use the function to create sliding windows by timestamp.

Looking forward to your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It will be much easier to answer your question if we see your data, as well as the expected results. Please see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to create a minimal, reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is `zoo::rollmean()`

You can simply apply it using `rollmean(x, 30)` where 30 is the 30-s sliding window.

I am limited to elaborate more since a reproducible example was not provided.